# How to Increase Spark Repartition With Column Expressions Performance

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, partition, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I have a performance problem in repartition and partitionBy operation in Spark.

My `df` is containing monthly data and i am partitioning data as `daily` with `dailyDt` column. My code is like below.

#### First attempt

This takes 3 minutes to finish, but many small files for each dailyDt partition.

```scala
df.repartition(600)
  .write
  .partitionBy("dailyDt")
  .mode(Overwrite)
  .parquet("/path..")
```

#### Second attempt

This is producing only 1 big file foreach day, so its not the solution.

```scala
df.repartition(20, $"dailyDt")
  .write
  .partitionBy("dailyDt")
  .mode(Overwrite)
  .parquet("/path..")
```

#### Current solution

Adding salt with 'rand' function, getting 20 files (getting same size for each file) for each day (as expected) but it is taking too much time to run.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
        
df.repartition(20, $"dailyDt", rand)
  .write
  .partitionBy("dailyDt")
  .mode(Overwrite)
  .parquet("/path..")
```

**So, i have a solution but its running long. How could i decrease execution time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it with repartitionByRange.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).